# ASUS Router Internal Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

I have a really weird problem am facing in my home network. My main internet connection is provided from an ISP who have their own modem, I have connected that modem to an ASUS router for better stats, management and so on.

The problem am facing is that sometimes I am not able to connect to some of my internal devices including the router's home page. Most of the time 192.168.1.1 will open fine but there are sometimes that page will not open even though everything else is working, it will just keep trying to load until it says page is not available. Some problem with my printer, sometimes the printer's IP is working fine and I can print wirelessly but some other times it will not work even though the printer is working and the whole network is fine.

Any idea what might be causing this issue? At first I thought it could be duplicate IPs which shouldn't happen given the ASUS router I have so I assigned each device it's own static IP address but still same problem.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you put your modem in bridge mode?

Comment: How did you connect the modem to the router? LAN-to-LAN or LAN-to-WAN? How is the router configured? Is it actually routing? Is their modem also a router? Is it in bridge mode?

Comment: No it isn't in bridge mode, the modem is connected to the router LAN to WAN and in the modem I have disabled DHCP & WiFi so only the router should be handling that. @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your problem might be that you have DHCP pools enabled on both routers.  Turn off the DHCP pool on the ISP provided modem and leave the pool enabled on your ASUS router.
Also, when setting static IP addresses, make sure that your IP addresses are outside the bounds of your DHCP pool range.

Comment: I have DHCP enabled only on the router and not the modem. Also I have set the statis IPs up to 25 and the DHCP pool starts from 30. @pythonian

Comment: Ah! Very good @yl_ksa.  How are you connected?

Wall----(port?)ISPModem(port?)-------(port?)ASUS

Please tell me port numbers and also if they are WAN and/or LAN ports.